# Failed Drive Stuck HP Smart Array P410

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

I have been having some issues with intermittent failure and rebuild messages on our HP DL160 G6 with P410 controller.

As part of troubleshooting I replaced the SATA cable, and on boot up, now the controller is stuck in **Interim Recovery Mode**. It thinks that a drive has failed but is still connected(?), and there's an unassigned drive that it hasn't started rebuilding to.

```
=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array P410 in Slot 0 (Embedded)     (sn: )

  Port Name: 1I
  Port Name: 2I
  array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (50.0 GB, RAID 5, Interim Recovery Mode)
      logicaldrive 2 (10.9 TB, RAID 5, Interim Recovery Mode)

      physicaldrive 1I:0:3 (port 1I:box 0:bay 3, SATA, 0 MB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:5 (port 2I:box 0:bay 5, SATA, 4000.7 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:6 (port 2I:box 0:bay 6, SATA, 4000.7 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:8 (port 2I:box 0:bay 8, SATA, 4000.7 GB, OK)

   unassigned

      physicaldrive 2I:0:7 (port 2I:box 0:bay 7, SATA, 4000.7 GB, OK)
```

I have tried `ctrl slot=0 array A remove drives=1I:0:3` to remove the failed one, and `ctrl slot=0 array A add drives=2I:0:7` to add the unassigned one to start the rebuild.

Both commands fail with the following error:

```
Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the
   "show" command on devices to show additional details about the
   configuration.
Reason: Array is transforming
```

It's a RAID 5 array of 4x4TB drives.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What's the firmware version on the controller?

Comment: 6.64, thanks for the reply

Comment: Did a disk actually fail?

Comment: No. I pulled out the supposed 'failed' disk to test and it spun up fine, which concerns me...

Comment: The may _could_ be bad. Not all failures are mechanical.

Comment: True. I should probably add the 'failed' drive is an RMA replacement from WD after a previous 'failure'. I know it's possible, but the chances of both failing are so slim. I don't think I can count on one hand the number of genuine HD failures I've encountered across my career

Comment: I think your disk is in the wrong port or connected to the wrong cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you connect the drive to the same port on the backplane, or reorient the cable to get that drive into position 1. Otherwise, it won't be detected.

---

Edit:

It looks like your disk is in the wrong port or connected to the wrong cable.

Comment: I had inadvertedly re-connected the plane to the wrong port. I am still getting bay 3 drive failure messages though. I'll RMA the drive.

Comment: Eject failed disk, enter hpacucli command `rescan` and show all output of command `ctrl all show config`